# Gesture recognizer with pagecontrol and three views

Tags: ios, ios4

I'm trying to make a "rolling" view like the main "desktop" of the iphone.
I have 3 views with a *page control* and I would like to enable a swipe to browse the views.

I do not use storyboarding but only gestures.

Could someone help me?

What is the main method to use to enable this features??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only 3 pages, you can probably just place your views in UIScrollView, turn on paging for that scroll view, and then set your view controller as a delegate for that scroll view, and update the paging control in scrollViewDidScroll.

For more info, take a look at the WWDC 2010 session videos on UIScrollView:

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

There's also sample code that shows this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You want a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`. No need for gesture recognizers.

You can connect the page control to the scroll view by updating it from the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method of your [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate).